# create a new Column with value derived from original column

Tags: mysql, database, calculated-columns, derived-column

The question is how to add a new column with derived value. I have the following table named Character

```
Name      PointsTotal
Kat       310
Mat       410
Sam       550
Ram       660
```

I want the result to display the new column name Level which is based on PointsTotal.The rule is if Points total<400 than Level should be 1, if it is >400 and <500 than level should be 2 and so on. The result should look like

```
Name PointsTotal Level
Kat  310         1
Mat  410         2
Sam  550         3
Ram  660         4
```

Comment: 'add a new column ' - do you mean to the table or as part of a query? If the latter use a case statement.

Comment: Let's hope it's the latter

Comment: just add to the query. This is only for showing result.